# Responsive Font-Sizes: Which values are appropriate?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm currently occupied with responsive font-sizes. 
How units like vh, vw, vmin are meant is clear to me.

But I'm not able to accomplish something convincingly with them. 
The are either to large on large screen-size and then to small on small screens. Or vice-versa.

**Are there any general rules which values are appropriate?**

For example: h1 should be 2vw, h2 should be 1.5vw, p should be 1vw and so on ...

**Should I use vw or vh and why?**

Comment: I think this is more like a design question, not a code question

Comment: maybe this can help you [https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hackape is correct in their comment that this is not a code question. But to answer the actual question of "Which values are appropriate" in a code sense then the answer is all of them.

You can use `vw` to make your fonts grow/shrink with the width of the viewport. Alternatively you can use `vh` to make the grow/shrink in relation with the height.

As for your point about being too large or too small, you have at least two options.

### Media Queries

Using media queries you can control font sizes for specific sizes the same way you can control any other part of the website in a responsive design.

```
p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  p {
    font-size: 1vw;
  }
}
```

Don't use that example for design advice but you can see how you can easily control the values appropriately based on your choices.

### CSS Locks

A good alternative to this is a technique called CSS Locks. This is not actually a part of CSS, instead it is a formula for CSS Calc that is known to work very well for giving a minimum and maximum to font sizes.

There are a few good articles about CSS Locks, one of them is [Florens Verschelde's The math of CSS Locks](https://fvsch.com/css-locks/).

Here's an example from [CSS-Tricks' Fluid Typography](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/):

```
p {
  font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}
```

As you can see, no media queries are used. And if you want to use `vw` or `vh` you can.

Comment: Great!  :)  Many thanks for your answer and the articles.